# How to concat values without NULL results (Snowflake)

Tags: sql, string, concatenation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to concat not null values in Snowflake.

My current code:

```
            CONCAT(
                CASE WHEN Red='TRUE' THEN 'Red, ' ELSE '' END ||
                CASE WHEN Blue='TRUE' THEN 'Blue, ' ELSE '' END ||
                CASE WHEN Black='TRUE' THEN 'Black, ' ELSE '' END ||
                CASE WHEN White='TRUE' THEN 'White, ' ELSE '' END)

Return: 
Red, White, Black,
Black,
...

Want:
Red, White, Black
Black
```

In Mysql, I would use Concat_WS, but in Snowflake if one value is NULL, NULL will be in Return:

```
            CONCAT_WS(', ',
                CASE WHEN Red='TRUE' THEN 'Red' ELSE NULL END,
                CASE WHEN Blue='TRUE' THEN 'Blue' ELSE NULL END,
                CASE WHEN Black='TRUE' THEN 'Black' ELSE NULL END,
                CASE WHEN White='TRUE' THEN 'White' ELSE NULL END)
```

Comment: You can still use CONCAT_WS if you ensure none of the values can return NULL by including the ELSE '' from your first example.

Answer (score 10):

A bit late, but I had the same problem and found a different solution:

As was rightly pointed out before `CONCAT` and `WS_CONCAT` always return `NULL` when any argument to them is `NULL`.

But, as Snowflake has a concept of `ARRAY`s (i.e. support for semi-structured data), i.e. we can do the following:

1. Collect the raw values into an array with `array_construct`
2. Remove `NULL` values from the array with `array_compact`
3. Use `array_to_string` to concatenate the remaining array items into a string

Here's the modifief code, using arrays:

```sql
select array_to_string(array_compact(array_construct( 
          CASE WHEN Red = 'TRUE' THEN 'Red' ELSE NULL  END,
          CASE WHEN Blue = 'TRUE' THEN 'Blue' ELSE NULL END, 
          CASE WHEN Black = 'TRUE' THEN 'Black' ELSE NULL END,
          CASE WHEN White = 'TRUE' THEN 'White' ELSE NULL END)), ', ') as result
FROM values 
( true, true, false, false ),
( true, false, false, true ),
( false, false, true, false ),
( false, true, false, true ),
( true, true, true, true )
v(red,blue,black,white);
```

EDIT: You can also use [`array_construct_compact`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_construct_compact.html), which is a condensed version of `array_construct` and `array_compact`

Answer (score 2):

You can use RTRIM to remove ending comma:

```
select RTRIM(CONCAT( 
          CASE WHEN Red = 'TRUE' THEN 'Red, ' ELSE ''  END,
          CASE WHEN Blue = 'TRUE' THEN 'Blue, ' ELSE '' END, 
          CASE WHEN Black = 'TRUE' THEN 'Black, ' ELSE '' END,
          CASE WHEN White = 'TRUE' THEN 'White, ' ELSE '' END ),', ' ) result
FROM values 
( true, true, false, false ),
( true, false, false, true ),
( false, false, true, false ),
( false, true, false, true ),
( true, true, true, true )
v(red,blue,black,white);

+-------------------------+
| RESULT                  |
+-------------------------+
| Red, Blue               |
| Red, White              |
| Black                   |
| Blue, White             |
| Red, Blue, Black, White |
+-------------------------+
```

You may also consider to convert empty string to NULL using NULLIF function:

```
select NULLIF( RTRIM(CONCAT( 
          CASE WHEN Red = 'TRUE' THEN 'Red, ' ELSE ''  END,
          CASE WHEN Blue = 'TRUE' THEN 'Blue, ' ELSE '' END, 
          CASE WHEN Black = 'TRUE' THEN 'Black, ' ELSE '' END,
          CASE WHEN White = 'TRUE' THEN 'White, ' ELSE '' END ),', ' ), '' )result
FROM values 
( false, false, false, false )
v(red,blue,black,white);
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that your expression does quite what you want, but you need to remove the trailing comma. You can use `TRIM()` for this:

```
TRIM(', ' FROM 
       CASE WHEN Red   = 'TRUE' THEN 'Red, '   ELSE '' END  
    || CASE WHEN Blue  = 'TRUE' THEN 'Blue '   ELSE '' END 
    || CASE WHEN Black = 'TRUE' THEN 'Black, ' ELSE '' END 
    || CASE WHEN White = 'TRUE' THEN 'White, ' ELSE '' END
)
```

Note that there is no point using *both* `||` and `CONCAT()`: I removed the surrounding `CONCAT()`.