# Concat by Column Names using Binary Results

Tags: sql, string, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'd like to concat column names if true as per below:

Input Table:

| ID | Flag1 | Flag2 | Flag3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | True | False | True |
| 2 | False | True | True |

Desired Output Table:

| ID | Flags |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Flag1, Flag3 |
| 2 | Flag2, Flag3 |

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61964538/how-to-concat-values-without-null-results-snowflake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so chaining a few commands together, [IFF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/iff) to test the column value and produce the name or null, [ARRAY_CONSTRUCT_COMPACT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_construct_compact) to strip out the null values, and [ARRAY_TO_STRING](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_to_string) to put it together nicely.

and using a CTE for data:

```
with data(id, flag1, flag2, flag3) as (
    select * from values
    (1, True,   False,  True),
    (2, False,  True,   True)
)
select 
    id
    ,iff(flag1,'flag1', null) as c1
    ,iff(flag2,'flag2', null) as c2
    ,iff(flag3,'flag3', null) as c3
    ,array_construct_compact(c1,c2,c3) as a
    ,array_to_string(a, ', ') as result
from data
order by 1;
```

| ID | C1 | C2 | C3 | A | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | flag1 | null | flag3 | [ "flag1", "flag3" ] | flag1, flag3 |
| 2 | null | flag2 | flag3 | [ "flag2", "flag3" ] | flag2, flag3 |

which can be folded up like:

```
select 
    id
    ,array_to_string( 
        array_construct_compact(
            iff(flag1,'flag1', null),
            iff(flag2,'flag2', null), 
            iff(flag3,'flag3', null)
            )
        , ', '
        ) as flags
from data
order by 1;
```

to give:

| ID | FLAGS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | flag1, flag3 |
| 2 | flag2, flag3 |

Answer (score 1):

The following query using a CASE expression and the CONCAT function shall work for you in snowflake.

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    RTRIM(CONCAT(
        CASE WHEN Flag1 THEN 'Flag1, ' ELSE '' END,
        CASE WHEN Flag2 THEN 'Flag2, ' ELSE '' END,
        CASE WHEN Flag3 THEN 'Flag3, ' ELSE '' END
    ), ', ') AS Flags
FROM 
    YourTable;
```

Output :

| ID | Flags |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Flag1, Flag3 |
| 2 | Flag2, Flag3 |

As I don't have any free tool to [show you demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/OKifVabw); I am trying to show you demo here using equivalent query in other database

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the CASE statement, CONCAT function, and string aggregation function like you can use the LISTAGG function.

Here's an example SQL query:

```
SELECT ID, LISTAGG(CASE
                WHEN Flag1 = TRUE THEN 'Flag1'
                ELSE NULL
              END || ', ' ||
              CASE
                WHEN Flag2 = TRUE THEN 'Flag2'
                ELSE NULL
              END || ', ' ||
              CASE
                WHEN Flag3 = TRUE THEN 'Flag3'
                ELSE NULL
              END, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) AS Flags
FROM InputTable
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: The input data is appears to just be a single for for ID 1, thus there grouping/aggregation has not impact. Also in Snowflake concatenation `||` of `null` values produces null, and lastly, the `else null` is not required, as null is the default.